# Notepad++ extract links from html tag with class

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a text which consists of different html elements and links like this one: `<a href="somelink" class="details btn secondary large">`. I want to extract links from a href tag. What are possibilities here ?

Comment: What do you mean by extract? Do you want to get a list of link targets?

Comment: Yes, i want to get list of links which are defined in href attribute. 

Or atleast I want to remove everything except `<a href="somelink" class="details btn secondary large">` these tags.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's impossible to parse an arbitrary `HTML` document with regular expressions. You may be able to parse your particular file though. Please post the text you're dealing with.

Comment: [Relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) when it comes to parsing arbitrary HTML with regex.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19717092/regex-filter-links-from-a-document